# Dini Derivatives Properties proof.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, limsup-and-liminf

Theorem. Let $f$ be defined and finite on the interval $[a,b]$. Then 
$$\overline{D}f(a) = D^{+} f(a)$$
$$\underline{D} f(a) = D_{+} f(a)$$ 
$$\overline{D} f(b) = D^- f(b)$$
$$ \underline{D} f(b) = D^- f(b)$$
if $x_0 \in (a,b)$
$$\overline{D} f(x_0) = \sup \{ D^+ f(x_0), D^- f(x_0) \}$$
$$ D^+ (-f(x)) = - D_+ f(x)$$
Can someone help me with proof these two properties. I don't know where to start and it's my first meeting with Dini dervatives.
$\overline{D}$-upper derivative, $D^-$ left upper derivative.

Comment: I don't have time now to say much (however, the "sup" can be replaced by "max" since only two values are involved), but I'll mention that Edward James McShane's book [**Integration**](https://www.thehauntedbookshop.com/pages/books/069734/edward-james-mcshane/integration) has possibly the most detailed-filled treatment of these kinds of identities I've seen anywhere. See pp. 26-44 for an extensive treatment of lim-inf and lim-sup of a function, and see pp. 188-193 for a lot of proved results about Dini derivates.

Comment: **Hints:** For the multiplication by $-1$ property, this is an immediate consequence of the fact that $\limsup (-g) = - (\liminf g).$ Here, $g$ is the appropriate difference quotient function for $f$ computed with $x_0$ fixed. If you can't cite this property, then prove it. For the upper derivative property, $\geq$ is immediate. (Why?) To show $\leq,$ use the fact that if a sequence $\{t_n\}$ approaches $t,$ then infinitely many terms must lie on one side of $t.$

Comment: Thanks you for information that book is awesome. It's really easy to understand.

Comment: While looking something up just now I came across [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1437043/13130), which although not directly connected with what you're asking about, is sufficiently related that it may be of interest.