Describing the size of the first step in a discrete (cumulative) distribution function.
Suppose we have the following simple, discrete df:
$$
F_X(x) = 0: ~ x <0; \qquad 0.2: ~ 0 \leq x < 1; \qquad 0.4: ~ 1 \leq x < 2,
$$
and so on. How do we talk about the size of the first step? If $p_x$ is the associated probability mass function, do we say $p_x(0) =F_X(0) - \lim_{x \to -\infty} F_X(x) = 0.2$? Or can we pick a point and say, for example,  $p_x(0) = F_X(0) - F_X(-3) = 0.2$? I'm leaning toward the first optio, but I'm wondering if there is a convention for this, or at least an accepted notation.

Are you searching for notations for one-sided limits? If so, here's a question on MSE that might help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436963/notation-of-one-sided-limits. Also, I don't see any reason the first step is "located" at $0$. One way, in this very context, could be to define $$\inf_{a\in\mathbb R}\left{\lim_{x\to a^-}F_X(x)\ne \lim_{x\to a^+}F_X(x)\right}$$
I'm open to criticism.

Thanks for weighing in. By the first step I mean the first change in the function as $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.
